# Time complexity of JSON serialization/parse

Tags: json, optimization, time, complexity-theory

I have a project that use JSON as cross-language serialization to pass around data. Recently the size of the data grows a little huge (10k length list of objects). It takes python standard json library around 20 seconds to serialize the data.

I am working to optimize the time. While switch to other json serializer (cjson, simplejson, ujson) can speed things up quite a bit, I am start to wondering the time complexity of JSON serialization. If the relationship is not linear (say if it is n^2) I can easily chop the data in chunks and reduce the time significantly.

From what I guessed, the complexity should really depends on the input data. But is there a worst-case/average estimation available? A link to reference will be highly appreciated too.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on what type of data you're sending in a 10k post? Is this a dataset of queried records or something like that?

Comment: Creating some data yourself in order to analyze the time complexity should be pretty fast to accomplish :-)

Comment: @JonathanM basically yes. The problem being the programmer that consumes my data refused to query as they need, but insist to get the big chunk of data in one shot.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke That's true, I just wonder if it's already been analyzed/proved in theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've benchmarked the time complexity with this code:

```
import json
import random
import time

Ns = 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 600000, 1000000
for N in Ns:
    l = [random.random() for i in xrange(N)]
    t0 = time.time()
    s = json.dumps(l)
    t1 = time.time()
    dt = t1-t0
    print "%s %s" % (N, dt)
```

On my machine, the outcome is:

```
10 7.20024108887e-05
100 0.000385999679565
1000 0.00362801551819
10000 0.036504983902
100000 0.366562128067
200000 0.73614192009
300000 1.09785795212
600000 2.20272803307
1000000 3.6590487957
```

First column: list length; second column: time for serialization. Plotting (with for example xmgrace) reveals an ideal linear relation.

Comment: I tried with a nested data structure that similar to the data I used, the results shows exponential. I guess it worth the effort to chop it in chunks.